# Docx4j variableReplace with styling

Tags: java, ms-word, docx, docx4j

I want to creating new Word document from a model document (.docx) and replace some text with styling.

How can I style the `firstName` in Bold and `message` as yellow highlight color?

My Code is below:

```java
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(templateInputStream);

MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);

HashMap<String, String> variables = new HashMap<>();
variables.put("firstName", "fileName123");
variables.put("lastName", "lastName345");
variables.put("message", "messsssssss");

documentPart.variableReplace(variables);

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

wordMLPackage.save(outputStream);

return outputStream.toByteArray();
```

A screenshot of my starting model [sic: template] docx is shown below:

[image: screenshot]

A screenshot of my expected result is the following:

[image]

Comment: I changed your term "template" to starting document. "Template" is a term of art in Word jargon, much different from the general English-language word. Here is my web page on templates: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm --- Why not use bookmarks in Word rather than variables. Word is designed to use bookmarks as spaces. Otherwise, consider using named Content Controls if you want to leave the space variable.

Answer (score 0):

Apply your desired run formatting in the source document, taking care not to "split" the run.  So, for example:

```
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:b/>
                <w:bCs/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>${firstName}</w:t>
        </w:r>
```

If Word is splitting your runs, turn off grammar and spelling correction.

If necessary, unzip the source document and check/edit in a text editor.